# Ansible: Kubectl snap installation failed

Tags: ansible, kubectl

Here is my play to install the `kubectl` from the  snap package manager

```
- name: Install the kubectl snap package
  snap:
    name: kubectl
    channel: "1.13/stable"
    classic: yes
    state: present
```

But I am getting the following error

```
> {"changed": false, "channel": "1:13/stable", "classic": true, "cmd":
> "sh -c \"/usr/bin/snap install --classic --channel 1:13/stable
> kubectl\"", "msg": "Ooops! Snap installation failed while executing
> 'sh -c \"/usr/bin/snap install --classic --channel 1:13/stable
> kubectl\"', please examine logs and error output for more details.",
> "rc": 1, "stderr": "error: snap \"kubectl\" is not available on
> 1:13/stable but is available to\n       install on the following
> tracks:\n\n       latest/stable  snap install --stable kubectl\n      
> 1.17/stable    snap install --channel=1.17 kubectl\n       1.16/stable    snap install --channel=1.16 kubectl\n       1.15/stable    snap
> install --channel=1.15 kubectl\n       1.14/stable    snap install
> --channel=1.14 kubectl\n       1.13/stable    snap install --channel=1.13 kubectl\n       1.12/stable    snap install --channel=1.12 kubectl\n       1.11/stable    snap install --channel=1.11 kubectl\n       1.10/stable    snap install --channel=1.10 kubectl\n       1.9/stable     snap install --channel=1.9 kubectl\n       1.8/stable     snap install --channel=1.8 kubectl\n       1.7/stable     snap install --channel=1.7 kubectl\n       1.6/stable     snap install --channel=1.6 kubectl\n       1.5/stable     snap install --channel=1.5 kubectl\n\n       Please be mindful that different tracks may include different features.\n       Get more information
> with 'snap info kubectl'.\n", "stderr_lines": ["error: snap
> \"kubectl\" is not available on 1:13/stable but is available to", "   
> install on the following tracks:", "", "       latest/stable  snap
> install --stable kubectl", "       1.17/stable    snap install
> --channel=1.17 kubectl", "       1.16/stable    snap install --channel=1.16 kubectl", "       1.15/stable    snap install --channel=1.15 kubectl", "       1.14/stable    snap install --channel=1.14 kubectl", "       1.13/stable    snap install --channel=1.13 kubectl", "       1.12/stable    snap install --channel=1.12 kubectl", "       1.11/stable    snap install --channel=1.11 kubectl", "       1.10/stable    snap install --channel=1.10 kubectl", "       1.9/stable     snap install --channel=1.9 kubectl", "       1.8/stable     snap install --channel=1.8 kubectl", "       1.7/stable     snap install --channel=1.7 kubectl", "       1.6/stable     snap install --channel=1.6 kubectl", "       1.5/stable     snap install --channel=1.5 kubectl", "", "       Please be mindful that different tracks may include different features.", "       Get more information
> with 'snap info kubectl'."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The play works as expected.

```
- name: Install the kubectl snap package
  snap:
    name: kubectl
    channel: "1.13/stable"
    classic: yes
    state: present
```

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.12", GitCommit:"a8b52209ee172232b6db7a6e0ce2adc77458829f", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-17T19:01:20Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Your error message states that it failed to install `1:13/stable` version of kubectl.

```
Ooops! Snap installation failed while executing 'sh -c \"/usr/bin/snap install --classic --channel 1:13/stable kubectl\"', please examine logs and error output for more details.
```

It is possible that you keyed in a wrong channel version while executing the playbook. The channel must be one of the channels listed [here](https://snapcraft.io/kubectl).

Comment: channel version is existing,that's what I am confused.When i try `latest/stable` it works

Comment: Recheck your playbook, your error message gives a different channel version (`1:13/stable`). This does not exist

Comment: But `1.13/stable` exists in repo

Comment: Yes, from the error it looks like your playbook had `1:13/stable` instead of `1.13/stable`

Comment: Ahh got it One more question do you how to reinstall this play ??

Comment: Just execute it again. Ansible takes care of idempotency.

Comment: Tried I can still see the older version not the newer one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211121/discussion-between-franklinsijo-and-iam-batman).